# How can I minify HTML, CSS and JavaScript files in DocPad?

Tags: docpad

I would like to minify HTML, CSS and JavaScript files when I hit `docpad generate`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this. The most prominent and most immediate way is to modify your [docpad configuration file](http://bevry.me/docpad/config) to trigger an external tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to minify your assets via the [grunt minify task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/docs/task_min.md). [Here is a gist that showcases this.](https://gist.github.com/3898915)

Alternatively, there is also [Cloudflare](http://cloudflare.com) which is an amazing website DNS server that also acts as a CDN for your website's content, and minifies your assets automatically post-deployment. [Read more here.](http://blog.cloudflare.com/an-all-new-and-improved-autominify)

Also, while it isn't minify related, you can also concatenate your scripts with [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4398093). Grunt also has a more straightfoward way of concatenating as well via the [grunt concat task.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/0.3-stable/docs/task_concat.md)

Eventually, perhaps plugins will do this automatically, but considering the fickleness with concatination it could be a while.

Answer (score 3):

- Use gruntjs for JS files. (Grunt will hook up into docpad generate)
- Use grunt-contrib-mincss for css files.
- Use grunt-contrib-htmlmin for html files.
- Use grunt-compress for compressing all files.

For list of all grunt plugins look here:
https://github.com/gruntjs